# How do I trigger a lightbox with jquery, only if the user has scrolled below the fold

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-waypoints

Setup: SO i have a header div 960px x 400px, enough to fit a youtube video on the left and some other bullet points and a call to action on the right. That div is hidden and only displayed on a button click. Easy enough.

But I would like to show that same hidden content within a colorbox, but only if that user has scrolled 750px down, which would be to the end of my fold. If say they are only 400px scrolled down and they click a play button then they should get shot back up to the top of the screen and watch the video in the header div mentioned above.

I was thinking of using waypoints to help with this functionality but there may be a better way.

let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="#">Play</a>` will take the user to the top of the document. Make sure your click handler returns true and doesn't stopPropagation.

Answer (score 0):

Something you can consider for scrolling is the `.scroll()` from jQuery (read [here](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)) and the `.scrollTo()` [plugin for jQuery](http://flesler.blogspot.ch/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)

This is an example I made in [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WDDAS/)

```
$(function(){
$(window).scroll( function() {
    var scrolled = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(scrolled > 150) {
        $('#up').fadeIn();
    } else if(scrolled < 150) {
        $('#up').fadeOut();
    }
});
    $('#up').click(function(){
        $.scrollTo('#Top');
    });
});
```

In this example when the `window` is scrolled more than `150px`, the `#up` div will show. If the position on the scroll bar is `top`, the `#up` div will hide. Clicking the `#up` div will automatically scroll to the div `#top` (see fiddle).

I think this with some changes will get you what you need.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I definitely appreciate your approach. My indication may have been a bit unclear, but I would only like to allow a light box the ability to be active if the user is below the fold?